# How to Send JSON data and another file in the same POST request?

Tags: android, json, postman

My post request should have 2 thing 1st json and 2nd file 
I am trying it on postman it is happening but I don’t understand how to do in android 
[image: postman]
This is how I am hitting URL using post man 
What is the best for this to be done from android side

Comment: Do you know how to use Retrofit or any other Http Client library?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari yes,I don’t want to use any 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 0):

use multipart request for android post. you can use [android networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) like this.

```
AndroidNetworking.upload(url)
                 .addMultipartFile("image",file)    
                 .addMultipartParameter("data",jsondata.tostring)
                 .setTag("uploadTest")
                 .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                 .build()
                 .setUploadProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesUploaded, long totalBytes) {
                      // do anything with progress 
                    }
                 })
                 .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                      // do anything with response                
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                      // handle error 
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: It is a library ,I don’t want you use any library

Comment: then you can create your costume multipart class. https://riptutorial.com/android/example/10717/use-httpurlconnection-for-multipart-form-data